# Quais são os padrões de organização de projeto?

Tags: metodologia, gerenciamento-de-projetos, organização-de-projeto

As grandes empresas utilizam no desenvolvimento de projetos metodologias que resultam numa organização de um software(pacotes, classes, interfaces). Há variados padrões que um programador pode usar, mas muitas pessoas assim como eu tenho dúvidas na escolha de um dentre vários. Minha questão é quais os padrões mais utilizados e quais suas finalidade?

> OBS: Eu sei que o tópico poderá ficar muito grande, minha sugestão seria que você apresente uns 2 ou 3 padrões que durante os anos se mostraram eficientes, suas finalidades e como realizar sua modelagem. Quero deixar meus projetos organizados sem a bagunça de várias classes ou métodos misturados. Podem postar metodologias que vocês conhecem ou utilizam.

Comment: O problema é que é difícil determinar uma resposta "vencedora" se você não deixar clara qual é a sua necessidade. Basicamente, muitas pessoas vão falar o jeito que fazem, e uma lista de sugestões estará formada, fugindo do modelo proposto pela site. Veja: [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/3117)

Comment: é justamente o que eu procuro que as pessoas deem sugestões de coisas q elas utilizam...

Comment: E é justamente o que foge do modelo do site, e é por isso que sua pegunta foi fechada. Talvez a mesma pergunta possa ser bem aceita no [chat], não custa nada tentar.